# How to use different model packages in different group when generate API client with go-swagger?

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-swagger

I have two groups of operation, for example: `task` and `file`. And their models are pre-defined in two packages, like: `my/task/models` and `my/file/models`.

When I generate the API client, I found that the `--existing-models` param seems can use only one package, and it will used in all groups.

Is there any way to use different model packages in different client groups?